# Show percentage of category relative to stacked bar in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a stacked bar chart with charts.js and I would like to show the relative percentage of a category in the tooltip when I hover over the category.
[image]

So even if the bar is not at max value, I want the categories of a bar to add up to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dataLabels plugin. I made an example for you on [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/cbalakus/9b531c6a/19/).

```
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            formatter: function(value, context) {
            if(context.chart.data.datasets[context.datasetIndex] != null){
                    var barTotal = context.chart.data.datasets.map(function(x){return x.data[context.dataIndex]}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                    return (value * 100 /  barTotal).toFixed(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to see the percentage on hover, you can check tooltip functions and aplly the same function for it.